# App returns weird values

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a weird problem with an app. On startup it plays a video clip, this is done by the use of threading. What I want to do is to make the main thread wait for the worker thread to finish before it continues.
However, whatever I do with the video instance within the thread I only get values that seems to be incorrect. For example video.GetHeight returns a negative integer value. IsPlaying always returns false even if the video is actually playing and so on.
The video starts and works perfectly but all the values from the other methods I try to call on the video instance within the thread returns weird values.
Anyone knows where the problem is?

Here is the Thread class:

```
private class ThreadClass extends Thread {
    public VideoView video;
    public int ID = -1;
    @Override public void run() {
        if(this.ID == 1)
        {
            video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.introvideo);
            video.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.intro);
            video.start();
            System.out.println("Input ID: " + this.ID);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("Unexpected ID (" + this.ID + ")");
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this even works. Why are you trying to do this from another thread? Views should only run on the UI (main) thread anyway.

Comment: The plan is to switch form when the video is done playing. Didn't find any method for doing so? If I apply it to change form after the play-method it changes form right away. So that's why I create a thread that is responsible for playing the video. And the main thread should wait for this thread to complete before it continues (change form).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UI threads. Check [this !](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)